# PHP login running every time page loads

Tags: php, html, authentication

Pages involved are:

1. login.php (login forms)
2. admin.php (dashboard)
3. post_ad.php (some random page)

My login pages works fine, then after login comes dashboard, which also works fine!

Problem comes when I go back to admin.php from post_ad.php, using a hyperlink, I redirect to login page! 
The code actually fails to understand that I have actually logined before correctly! 
Please help to out to rectify my problem!

**admin.php**

```
    include 'connection.php';
    $user = $_POST['user'];
    $pass = $_POST['pass'];

    if($user != 'zxc' && $pass != 'zxc')
    {
        header('Location: login.php');      
    }
    session_start();
    ?>

    <a href="post_ad.php">POST A NEW ADVERTISE</a>
```

I want the code to remember, untill I logout or close the windows, that I have logined once!

Comment: Have a look at the global variable `$_SESSION`

Comment: You really should use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Comment: use session_start at the top of page

Answer (score 4):

First of all in any page use session_start() at the top of the page not somewhere in middle of code.
in login.php File put user id in $_SESSION if user logged in successfully
for example

```
$_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id
```

Say $user_id stores username in your code

and at the top of login page use this code

```
@session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['user_id']) && $_SESSION['user_id']!='') {
    header("location: admin.php");
}
```

This will redirect you to admin page if user is logged in 
and in other pages you could use

```
@session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['user_id']) || $_SESSION['user_id']=='') {
    header("location: login.php");
}
```

This will redirect you to login page if user is not logged in

Comment: Shouldn't it be if empty check and not isset?

Comment: Well I cant use `$_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id` on my login page, coz there is no php code on it! its consist of simply forms

Answer (score 2):

You are checking posted variables from login page every time.

Which are not set when navigated from page other than login.

Store the values in sessions instead (on login page action).

```
$user = $_SESSION['user'];
$pass = $_SESSION['pass'];
```

And now check these values.

Also, don't forget to include `session_start()` in the beginning of the page.

Comment: I dont have any php code on login php! only forms! My php user and pass checking happens on admin.php